# Sometimes there is delay between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, no CPU usage

Tags: ios, delay, lag, viewwillappear, viewdidappear

I have a segue defined in storyboard from a table cell to a view controller using Modal

There are 20% of chance that the lag between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear will be extreme long (above 5 seconds), 80% of time the lag is within 1 second.

This happens even there is no code in viewDidload and viewWillAppear in the view controller.

But if I set the segue to "animation disabled", the lag get removed.

I have some other segue triggered from button in the same form and they works fine.

When it lags, there is no CPU load and the xcode is waiting for message (mach_msg_trap).

Here is the log, you can see the last segue takes 14.5 seconds.

```
2014-01-05 00:38:10.634 ATracker[29792:70b] ViewWillAppear finshed
2014-01-05 00:38:11.179 ATracker[29792:70b] ViewDidAppear started
2014-01-05 00:38:15.080 ATracker[29792:70b] ViewWillAppear finshed
2014-01-05 00:38:15.922 ATracker[29792:70b] ViewDidAppear started
2014-01-05 00:38:17.138 ATracker[29792:70b] ViewWillAppear finshed
2014-01-05 00:38:17.969 ATracker[29792:70b] ViewDidAppear started
2014-01-05 00:38:21.041 ATracker[29792:70b] ViewWillAppear finshed
2014-01-05 00:38:35.540 ATracker[29792:70b] ViewDidAppear started
```

Anyone has the same problem and how you fixed it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your issue is most likely related to the code in segue's destination view controller. There can be much reasons:1) networking code in main thread; 2) Huge (really huge) CoreData fetch; 3) Address book fetch etc. Note, that if you have tableView/collectionView in your vc their datasource methods are called between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

Comment: Thanks! I have created a new view controller without any code (default VC, no override) as the segue destination, but the problem persist. around 20% of chance I get a very slow popup. Also I have checked there is no network communication, the core data size is minimal (only 4 rows), no access to address book, etc. Also, there is no CPU load or memory consumption at that time. Is there any other possibility?